# Problema con cors react-ts(front) nestjs(back) deploy en vercel

Tags: reactjs, cors, nestjs

me ocurre algo un tanto extraño... llevo dias buscando configuraciones y cambiando cosas para PROD, tengo un frontend y una API desplegada en vercel, el problema es que no consigo conectarlas entre sí, me da "CORS ERROR" en cada llamada. lo extraño es que si tiro esa misma petición desde POSTMAN funciona bien ¿alguna idea de que puede ser? ya intente con configuraciones de cors de vercel en nestjs y habilitando los cors en el propio framework y tambien con la opcion de vite(react) "cors: true" pero no se soluciona